# How can I assign certain samples as negative samples when using sampled_softmax_loss in TensorFlow?

Tags: tensorflow

The API of *sampled_softmax_loss* goes like:

```py
tf.nn.sampled_softmax_loss(
    weights,
    biases,
    labels,
    inputs,
    num_sampled,
    num_classes,
    num_true=1,
    sampled_values=None,
    ...
)
```

I've noticed that arg `sampled_values` is the one which determines what negatives samples we take and it's returned by a `_candidate_sampler` function like `tf.random.fixed_unigram_candidate_sampler`.

And in `tf.random.fixed_unigram_candidate_sampler` we can decide the probability of each sample chosen as negative sample.

How can I assign certain sample as negative sample on purpose?

For instance, in the case of recommender system, I'd like to add some **hard negative** sample to the model. So I want the **hard negative** samples been chosen **for sure**, not by **probability** like in `_candidate_sampler` function

How can I assign certain samples as negative samples when using *sampled_softmax_loss* in TensorFlow?

Answer (score -1):

You need to understand that the sampler candidates function is only a remarks function and your question is right about how to create a negative sampler.

You don't need to create a negative sampler when you assigned a unique. The sampler is (`sampled_candidates`, `true_expected_count`, `sampled_expected_count`). Hard negative is when you add contrast values to significant the candidates. In this way, you can have it with distributions.

1. [Random Uniform Candidates Sampler](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/random/uniform_candidate_sampler)
2. [Candidate Sampling](https://www.tensorflow.org/extras/candidate_sampling.pdf)
3. [Sampled SoftMax](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/sampled_softmax_loss)

Simple: It is weight and bias are varies, and functions are the same.

```
import tensorflow as tf

weights = tf.zeros([4, 1])
biases = tf.zeros([4])
labels = tf.ones([4, 1])
inputs = tf.zeros([4, 1])
num_sampled = 1
num_classes = 1

true_classes = tf.ones([4, 4], dtype=tf.int64)
num_true = 4
num_sampled = 1
unique =True
range_max = 1

sampler = tf.random.uniform_candidate_sampler(
    true_classes,
    num_true,
    num_sampled,
    unique,
    range_max,
    seed=None,
    name=None
)

loss_fn = tf.nn.sampled_softmax_loss(
    weights,
    biases,
    labels,
    inputs,
    num_sampled,
    num_classes,
    num_true=1,
    sampled_values=sampler,
    remove_accidental_hits=True,
    seed=None,
    name='sampled_softmax_loss'
)
print( loss_fn )
```

Output: Value output as examples, and ran three times.

```
tf.Tensor([6.437752 6.437752 6.437752 6.437752], shape=(4,), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor([6.437752 6.437752 6.437752 6.437752], shape=(4,), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor([6.437752 6.437752 6.437752 6.437752], shape=(4,), dtype=float32)
```